# html element moves when content is added to other elements

Tags: html, css, dom

I have had this problem for quite some time, and i cant seem to get rid of it.

I have a relative parent div "wrapper"
Inside "wrapper" i have an absolute div "tweetHolder"
Inside "tweetHolder" i have 2 relative divs with class "tweets", these are horizontally aligned
(well, thats what i want..)
If both of these divs are empty, they are aligned.
If i add content to one, the other moves.

[URL to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2YXqc/)

Why is this and how can i get rid of it?

Thanks.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="tweetHolder">
        <div class="tweets EHBO">
            <div class="tweet">
                tweet 1
            </div><div class="tweet">
                tweet 2
            </div>
        </div
        ><div class="tweets drukte">
            <div class="tweet">
                tweet 3
            </div><div class="tweet">
                tweet 4
            </div><div class="tweet">
                tweet 5
            </div><div class="tweet">
            tweet 6
        </div>
    </div>          
</div>
```

```
#tweetHolder{
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
}

.tweets{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about that:

**CSS**

```
.EHBO{
    vertical-align: top;
    […]
}
```

The *default alignment* for inline elements is `baseline`, so using `top` will do the trick.

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/4Y3py/)